# why using ldapjs i can't connect to my server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, browserify

hello i had an issue with ldapjs when i create to my client and i try to connect to my server i had this error :

Uncaught TypeError: ldap://127.0.0.1:1389 is an invalid LDAP url (scope)

although my server run on this adress it's sure

here is my code

```
const ldap = require('ldapjs');

const client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});
```

i tried to install ldapjs-dtrace-fix but still the same

precision : i use browserify so that my code can be used in the browser

node version 16.2.0